# Why was Sokka not caught in the Episode of Boiling Rock in Avatar: The Last Airbender?

Tags: plot-explanation, avatar-the-last-airbender

In Season 3 Episode 15 of Avatar: The Last Airbender, Sokka was put in line when the Prison Warden found out that there is an impostor among the guards. All guards were asked to come out and Sokka was out too. Chit Sang, a prison inmate, was asked to point at the impostor and he pointed at another guard.

Sokka would have been caught outright because he was tying his hair using a blue band which is a colour of the water nation people and all other guards present tied their hair with a red band.

Why was he not caught because of this?

Comment: I always thought he knew that Sokka wasn't an actual guard, and was helping him by pointing at another guard.

Answer (score 5):

Sokka maintained his "new guy" cover pretty well even before that incident.

> Bully guard: The warden will deal with you soon. [Sokka closes the doors.] Can you believe this guy?
>
> Sokka[Playing along.]: Prisoners! Am I right?
>
> Bully guard: Ugh. Tell me about it.

Sokka is a pretty charismatic guy, you can see him establishing rapport with the other guards throughout the two episodes when he knocks down Zuko after his cover was blown, and then later when Sokka "roughs him up" in Part 2. We also know that the Warden has met Sokka at least once when he goes to see Chit Sang in the cooler, with Sokka standing guard.

Being "the guy who arrested Prince Zuko" helped him establish a degree of trust with some of the guards, making it so that he won't get called out as an outsider immediately.

Answer (score 4):

> Sokka would have been caught outright because he was tying his hair using a blue band which is a colour of the water nation people and all other guards present tied their hair with a red band.

Either an animation goof, or your overestimating the quality of the prison guards. I mean, ***a bunch of teenagers*** break out of the highest security prison in the Fire Nation. All the guards are shown to be very average to less than average intelligence.

If you think about it, Sokka was 15/16 at the time. He should have been called out on that. And realistically, he wouldn't have had a Fire Nation accent (the show doesn't address any accents), nor any Fire Nation skin tone or facial features. Sokka has blue eyes, a typically Water Bender trait. Prior to LOK, there was no interbreeding (considering a 100 year war).

Comment: I believe the age of any prisoner was not given, and some of the guards are of the same physique as Sokka. Inasmuch the Warden believe that no one has ever escaped from the Boiling rock prison makes security less tight, come to think of it, there is only one suppose way out of the place. It is rather an animation goof.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be a goof. You can check out this link for [*More*...](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/The_Boiling_Rock,_Part_2), although it might not be exactly what you want but might be helpful.